# I want to make it so when a checkbox is checked in my table, make it update a value for the specific user

Tags: php, html, ajax, html-table

I'm trying to make it so that when I click on a checkbox in a clients row in my table, i want my ajax to send a ID and the checkbox value (1 or 0 | 1 if checked | 0 if not checked) to my php code and update a column named 'enabled' for the specific user with 0 or 1. In my code, every time I click on the checkbox's label for it to update, it only updates one clients. The top of this:

[image]

to show you the checkbox's for each user - I used textbox's to, for now, display that the users id's are different but that it's only updating the top column - client id number 46

*Here is my code*

**HTML / PHP Table**

```
<td style="border: 1px solid #eee; text-align: center; font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'enabled','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);">
<input type="textbox" name="id_value" id="id_value" value="<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>">
<div class="checkbox checkbox-inverse checkbox-circle">
    <?php echo $faq[$k]["enabled"]  == 1 ?
    '<input id="checkbox-15" value="1" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked ><label for="checkbox-15">ON</label>'
    :
    '<input id="checkbox-15" type="checkbox" name="checkbox"><label for="checkbox-15">OFF</label>'; ?>

</div>
```

**My AJAX code**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {    
            $('#custom7').click(function() {
                if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $(this).siblings('label').html('on');
                } else {
                    $(this).siblings('label').html('off');
                }
            });
        });
        </script>

     <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[name=checkbox]').click(function() {

                var id = $('#id_value').val();

                if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                  var checkbox = '1';
                else
                  var checkbox = '0';

                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'includes/saveedit_members.php',
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        checkbox: checkbox
                    }
                }).done(function(response) {
                    window.location.replace("admin_members.php");
                });

            });
        });
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        function isNumberKey(evt) {
            myOutput = document.getElementById('add_user_result');
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
                myOutput.innerHTML = "<font style='color: red;'>You must fill in all the blanks.</font>";
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#add_user_result").hide();
        });

        function showEdit(editableObj) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
        } 

        function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url('images/spin.gif') no-repeat right");
            $.ajax({
                url: "includes/saveedit_members.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    window.location.replace("admin_members.php");
                }
           });
        }
```

**My PHP Receiving code**

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users set enabled = '".$_POST['checkbox']."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);
}

if(!isset($_POST['column']) || !isset($_POST["editval"]) || !isset($_POST["id"])) {
    header('Location: error-pages/index.php');
} else if(isset($_POST['column']) && isset($_POST["editval"]) && isset($_POST["id"])) {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users set " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$_POST["editval"]."' WHERE  id=".$_POST["id"]);
}
```

If anyone can help me out, remember, I'm wanting it to get the specific user's id so my php code can update the checkbox checked; not all or one of the clients.

Comment: I'm assuming each client has an ID. If so, get and pass the ID and edit row with the corresponding ID. Also, you shouldn't use `mysql_` as it has been deprecated for a while now. You should use `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: @Edward I'm using mysqli. lol. And also, I think my problem is becuase of the labels. Look at my code. The lables correspond to the checkbox's. It's only letting me update one checkbox becuase the label in the first part is the same as the other columns for all - <label for="checkbox-15"> . They're all checkbox-15. How can I make it so it changes the (for) checkbox / label commands for each user ?

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the "i" in `mysqli_` lol. You can do `checkbox-<?php echo $userId ?> and `$userId` should be the client's ID.

Comment: `<td style="border: 1px solid #eee; text-align: center; font-size: 11px;" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'enabled','<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);">
<input type="hidden" id="checkbox_usersId" value="<?php echo $faq[$k]["id"] ?>">
        <?php echo $faq[$k]["enabled"]  == 1 ?
            '<label><span class="label label-success">ON</span><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked></label>'
            :
            '<label><span class="label label-danger">OFF</span><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"></label>';
        ?>
</td>`

Comment: ^ That still doesn't work even when getting the value from a hidden input. It just only allows me to update the first client's row - number 46. no other one. Any ideas ?